# NetSuite Scripting 2.X - Upload Script File - UNEXPECTED_ERROR

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to upload a .js file (my suite script) on to NetSuite but am getting the following error.

> Fail to evaluate script:
> {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"missing
> ; before statement (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#15)","stack":[]}

[image]

The Script in question:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

    define([ 'N/record' ],function(record) {
        function afterSubmit(context) {
            
            // Load the record.
            var rec = record.load({
                type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
                id: 4918
            });
    
            let pricing_group = rec.getValue({
                fieldId: 'pricinggroup'
            });
    
            if (part_group == '') return;
    
            let current_desc = rec.getValue({
                fieldId: 'salesdescription'
            });
    
            rec.setValue({
                fieldId: 'salesdescription',
                value: pricing_group + ' | ' + current_desc,
                ignoreFieldChange: true,
                forceSyncSourcing: true
            });
     
            // Save the record.
            try {
                var recId = rec.save();
    
                log.debug({
                    title: 'Record updated successfully',
                    details: 'Id: ' + recId
                });
    
            } catch (e) {
                    log.error({
                        title: e.name,
                        details: e.message
                    });
            }
        }
        return {
            afterSubmit: afterSubmit
        };
    });
```

The syntax is correct running it on a syntax validator so I'm not sure where ';' is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your script (which are errors in SuiteScript 2.0, but not 2.1, namely you are using the `let` keyword, which is not valid in SuiteScript 2.0). The error actually is about one of them.

Try this:

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType UserEventScript
*/

define([ 'N/record' ],function(record) {
    function afterSubmit(context) {

        // Load the record.
        var rec = record.load({
            type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
            id: 4918
        });

        var pricing_group = rec.getValue({
            fieldId: 'pricinggroup'
        });

        if (part_group == '') return;

        var current_desc = rec.getValue({
            fieldId: 'salesdescription'
        });

        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'salesdescription',
            value: pricing_group + ' | ' + current_desc,
            ignoreFieldChange: true,
            forceSyncSourcing: true
        });

        // Save the record.
        try {
            var recId = rec.save();

            log.debug({
                title: 'Record updated successfully',
                details: 'Id: ' + recId
            });
        } catch (e) {
            log.error({
                title: e.name,
                details: e.message
            });
        }
    }
    return {
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };
});
```